# Formula help to check box if one of multiple school districts is present

Tags: formula

I need help with a formula checkbox. I have a list of 60 school districts that I want the box to be checked for. I have another text field that has over 400 School Districts (`Resident_School_District__c`) that I want my formula to scan for the 60 specific ones. Here is where I am stuck with a syntax error:

```
OR(
    CONTAINS(Resident_School_District__c, “Abbotsford”),
    CONTAINS(Resident_School_District__c, “ Antigo”),
    CONTAINS(Resident_School_District__c, “ Ashland”)
)
```

Maybe I need an IF but I had that in the front and it still threw an error.

Comment: Aside from the "smart" quotes (which may very well be the source of your issue), this looks fine from a syntax point of view. Whenever you're running into an error, it's always helpful to include the full text of the error you're getting, verbatim.

Comment: To make things a little clearer, I believe that string literals in formulas need to be enclosed in either single or double quotes. I don't think Salesforce knows what to do with "Smart" quotes.

Comment: If the Resident_School_District__c field is a multi select picklist then your formula will be like this.. IF(OR(
    INCLUDES(Resident_School_District__c, "Abbotsford"),
    INCLUDES(Resident_School_District__c, "Antigo"),
    INCLUDES(Resident_School_District__c, "Ashland")
),TRUE, FALSE)